# Two-finger scroll not working in some apps

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

Starting yesterday the two-finger scroll on my laptop seems to be acting up. It works perfectly in almost everything, except gedit and nautilus. I wasn't able to find any reference to this issue, albeit searching for a few hours.

Has anybody experienced this issue? Any ideas what could be the cause?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 (upgraded from 11.10) on an Asus U36SD with a Synaptics touchpad.

Comment: Same problem here, with Toshiba Satellite L750/L755

Comment: Here's the related bug - https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/982771

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is now fixed. I upgraded the xserver-xorg-input-synaptics package from precise-proposed.

For more information check https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/982771 (comment #6 for enabling precise-proposed).